# Tengo problemas al ejecutar npm run develop, me sale: gatsby-starter-hello-world@0.1.0 develop: `gatsby develop` npm ERR! Exit status 1

Tags: gatsby

Al ejecutar mi proyecto de Gatsby me sale:

not finished open and validate gatsby-configs, load plugins - 0.708s

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! gatsby-starter-hello-world@0.1.0 develop: `gatsby develop`
npm ERR! Exit status 1

```
module.exports = {
```

plugins: [
{
resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
options: {
name: `pages`,
path: `${__dirname}/src/pages`,
},
},

```
{
  resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
  options: {
    name: `post`,
    path: `${__dirname}/src/post`,
  },
},

{
  resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
  options: {
    name: `images`,
    path: `${__dirname}/src/images`,
  },
},

`gatsby-plugin-image`,
`gatsby-plugin-sharp`,
`gatsby-transformer-sharp`,

{
  resolve: `gatsby-plugins-mdx`,
  options: {
    extensions: [`.md`, `.mdx`],
    gatsbyRemarkPlugins: [
      {
        resolve: `gatsby-remark-images`,
        options: {
          maxWidth: 1200,
        },
      },
    ],
  },
},

{
  resolve: `gatsby-plugin-google-fonts`,
  options: {
    fonts: [`Roboto Mono`, `muli\:400, 400i, 700, 700i`],
    display: "swap",
  },
},
```

],
}